# Usage of a variable in an xPath expression

Tags: xpath, type-conversion, xslt-2.0

With the definition

```
<xsl:variable name="testVariable">
    <xsl:value-of select="'/author/'"/> 
</xsl:variable>
```

I was hoping that

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('./book',$testVariable,'@attribute')" />
```

returns the same like

```
<xsl:value-of select="./book/author/@attribute" />
```

But only the latter returns the actual value of the attribute, the first one just returns the path

```
./book/author/@attribute
```

How can I make the first one also return the value of the attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you construct strings in other programming languages and they get magically evaluated as program code? XSLT 3 has an `xsl:evaluate` instruction and some XSLT 1 or 2 processors have proprietary extensions to dynamically evaluate a string as an XPath expression. And of course for your restricted example doing e.g. `<xsl:variable name="child-name" select="'author'"/><xsl:value-of select="book/*[local-name() = $child-name]/@attribute"/>` is also a possible approach. In XSLT 3 you also have shadow attributes together with static parameters where `_select="book{$testParam}@attribute"` comes close

Comment: Herzlichen Dank - that solved the problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concat() function returns a string, it doesn't magically interpret that string as the source code of an XPath expression and then evaluate that expression.

Note also that

```
<xsl:variable name="testVariable">
    <xsl:value-of select="'/author/'"/> 
</xsl:variable>
```

can in 99% of cases be rewritten as

```
<xsl:variable name="testVariable" select="'/author/'"/>
```

which is not only less code, it's also a lot more efficient. (Sadly the other 1% of cases mean that the optimizer can't do this rewrite automatically.)

Usually you can achieve what you want using

```
select="/book/*[name()=$testVariable]/@attribute"
```

Occasionally you need to go a bit beyond that in which case you need something like `xsl:evaluate` in XSLT 3.0.